# database schema - mixing many to many and one to many relationships

Tags: sql, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a user model and a task model.

A user creates a task. This seems simple:
the task has a user_id foreign_key

But now we introduce sharing. Now a task has a many to many relationship with users, but belongs to an owner.

I could: 
- leave the user_id on tasks (perhaps renaming it to 'owner_id')
- AND have the many to many join table (user_tasks or shared_user_tasks) only model tasks that have been shared.

OR I could: 
- remove user_id on tasks
- AND make user_tasks a pure many to many relationship with a boolean 'is_owner' to tell me if that user is the owner

OR I could:
- remove user_id on tasks
- AND make user_tasks list both the shared_user_id AND owner_id
Which means that for some records, the shared_user_id and the owner_id would be the same number (harder queries than the above)

Which is more sound according to best practices?

Thank you for your time.

And, as the first answer suggest (though I'm a bit reticent to accept for some reason), conceptually, the two roles are different. One is a task owner, the other is simply someone who had the task shared with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "true" correct answer will depend on how these tables are being used, but it sounds like Option #1 should be your solution (task_table.owner_id and a separate M:M user_tasks table).  Even though a task owner and task user share the same source table, they are conceptually different and should be treated as such.  The logic of the table joins would be cleaner this way as well.

Comment: Interesting that you say conceptually different - I agree. I could see having the user_tasks table be shared_user_tasks, which I suppose is a conceptually different object than a user's tasks. I also believe that there is one query I would not be able to do easily, namely finding all tasks that a user has shared. I'll edit my original question to show you what I mean.

Comment: Think of it in terms of what defines your task and what makes for the most efficient SQL.  What if the task creator no longer "shared" the task?  Having the ownership flag in the task_users table would complicate this.

Answer (score 1):

Normalisation to the rescue! Probably..... (though there may be scope to denormalise for performance depending on your usage)

Table `Users` -- Stores information about users (who)

Table `Tasks` -- Stores information about tasks (what the task is, what it does, etc)

Table `UserTasks` -- M->M mapping.

Table `UserTaskTypes` -- Stores ("Owner", "Shared", "Consultant", "Manager", etc)

on `UserTasks` could look something like this (tsql)

```
CREATE TABLE UserTasks (
    [TaskID] INT,
    [UserID] INT,
    [UserTaskTypeID] INT,

    FOREIGN KEY FK_UserTasks_TaskID ([TaskID])
            REFERENCES Tasks ([TaskID]),

    FOREIGN KEY FK_UserTasks_UserID ([TaskID])
            REFERENCES Users ([UserID]),

    FOREIGN KEY FK_UserTasks_UserTaskTypeID ([UserTaskTpyeID])
            REFERENCES UserTaskTypes ([UserTaskTypeID]),

    PRIMARY KEY PK_UserTasks ([TaskID], [UserID], [UserTaskTypeID])
 )
```

And according to your business rules you could add CHECK CONSTRAINTS to enforce that every task only has one owner etc.

Choosing a clustered index for this may be as simple as clustering the PK but you'll shuffle data a lot on insets -- you may want a surrogate autonumber PK and enforce the uniqueness with a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I feel like this leans towards what the user_tasks with boolean is_owner (we will only have owner and not owner). I seem to flip back and forth, and can't justify the feeling that users - tasks- user_tasks is the most sound setup. I will discuss with my boss and come to a conclusion based upon what we will be querying most often.